# How do I do an "or" based search in sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have several categories of facets I'm looking for and in one I want, when the user clicks more than one filter in that particular category, to have the results sunspot returns include everything that matches either of the choices, not only both. I tried this:

```
@search = ProfileSearch.new(search_params) do
  facet_restriction = with(:grad_year,params[:grad_year])
  facet(:grad_year, :exclude => facet_restriction)
 end
```

But that doesn't seem to be working at all? Am I not using multiselect facets in the appropriate way or should I be looking at doing something entirely different?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
@search = ProfileSearch.search(search_params) do
  facet_restriction = with(:grad_year,params[:grad_year])
  facet(:grad_year, :exclude => facet_restriction)
 end
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave a "page has a redirect loop" sort of error. A lot of the problem I'm having understanding this is that the search model has a lot of methods in it that do various things. Like when you call new it runs it through the initialize method and there's another method later on that I think does the actual searching. I'll have to look into the flow of execution of it and get a better understanding but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
  grad_year_exclusions = []
  if params[:grad_year].present?
    grad_year_exclusions << with(:grad_year).any_of(params[:grad_year])
  end
  grad_year_exclusions.compact!
  grad_year_exclusions = nil if grad_year_exclusions.empty?
  facet(:grad_year, exclude: grad_year_exclusions)
```

(params[:grad_year] being an array)

Hope this helps.